# Cannot publish vendor config file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have installed `"hashids/hashids": "^4.1",` (from its [github repo](https://github.com/vinkla/hashids)) on my `Laravel Framework 8.68.0` project.

When I do, I do not get the config file.

```
admin@admin-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/project$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Vinkla\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider"
Xdebug: [Log Files] File '/tmp/xdebug/xdebug.log' could not be opened.
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9001 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
No publishable resources for tag [].
Publishing complete.
```

Any suggestions how to publish the config file for this library?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: I think there is no HashIdsServiceProvider in the source code repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no config file or Service Provider for that package as it isn't a Laravel specific package. You installed the wrong package it would seem. You are looking for the Laravel bridge package, `vinkla/laravel-hashids`, instead.

```
composer require vinkla/hashids
```